# eclipse indigo java perspective not visible

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I installed Eclipse Platform Version: 3.7.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. My Ubuntu Software Center shows that Eclipse Extensible Tool Platform and Java IDE (eclipse 3.7.2-1) is installed. Also Eclipse Integrated Development is also installed (eclipse-platform 3.7.2-1). However when I launch Eclipse, I am not able to get a Java perspective and not able to create a Java project. When I click on Open Perspective: I see CVS Repository Exploring, Debug, Resource (default) and Team Synchronizing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can click open perspective > others  and find Java perspective. please refer this picture:
[image]

Comment: When I click on Open Perspective -> Other, I just see the following four options: CVS Repository Exploring, Debug, Resource (default), Team Synchronization.

Comment: May be you need download and install it again.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem.  The only difference is I downloaded the Java EE updates through eclipse...

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not install Eclipse from any Linux repository or package manager; just download it directly from [the Eclipse web site](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). Also make sure you're using the Oracle JDK, not gcj. There are many problem reported with running Eclipse under gcj. To specify the JVM for Eclipse to run in, use [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

Second, what you have is the *Eclipse Platform*, which does not include any IDE features; it's just the base platform on which Eclipse is built (another problem with getting Eclipse from a linux repo is that you don't really know what they've packaged and delivered to you). For Java development, you probably want the **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** or **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** packages from the downloads page.

Answer (score 0):

Close Eclipse and rename the `.eclipse` directory in your home directory with another name, for example `.eclipseSAVE`.

Restart Eclipse and in perspective you should find Java.